# Firefox needs debugging

Tags: firefox, debug

Since this morning whenever I try to login to Stack Overflow, Firefox needs a debug. I am not able to pinpoint the problem - can anyone help?

I've tried rebooting my system but the problem still persists. If I use Internet Explorer or Chrome they both work fine.

Anything except a reinstall will be helpful.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try disabling all your extensions and restarting firefox.

If that fixes it, re-enable them one by one until the problem comes back.

Then uninstall that extension, or submit a bug to its developer.

Comment: thnx Blorgbeard